# Javascript - onclick - bubbling - orignating element

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, element

**Background**:
I'm currently writing a greasemonkey script that embeds/modifies a specific page's html. The page is setup with 3 nested divs. Of those 3 divs, I can only add an event listener to the outer most div(This is due to other events and the such already added to the elements). With the inner most div, links are added via AJAX/COMET. As with the inner divs, I can not add event handlers to these links due to the page's current event handlings.

**What I need**: When a link in the inner most div is clicked, the event will bubble up to the outer most div. From the outer most div, is there a way 1: to tell if it was a link clicked in the inner most div, and if so, 2: how to get that link's href

Please no jQuery solutions. It seems a bit over doing it sense this is the only javascript that will be embedded into the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a simple cross-browser event listener and the `event.target` (or `event.srcElement` in IE), like so:

```
var addEvent = function (el, ev, fn) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('on' + ev, fn);
    } else {
        el['on' + ev] = fn;
    }
};

var outer = document.getElementById('outer');

addEvent(outer, 'click', function(ev){
    ev = ev || window.event;
    var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
    alert(target.href);
});
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AEUj7/2)

Comment: I won't be needing IE support so ev.target is fine. Also, why not just document.getElementById('outer').addEventListner('click',function (ev) {...}); instead of creating a function for it?

Comment: @SReject—usually what is posted here is an example of a solution, you can use it however you like (or not). There are still a lot of browsers in use that support the IE event model (not all are IE), not accommodationg such users in a general web page is not a good idea.

Comment: @RobG the part of my reply about IE was to clearify that the mistype about target wasn't really a big deal. I understand the formatting, but was wondering if there was a specific reason(other than crossbrowser support) for the function. I apologize if I came off as ignorant :)

Comment: @SReject—not at all, there was no context for your statement is all. You never know where code will end up so a bit of cross-browser support never goes astray. :-)